# Parallel.For freezes after around 1370 iterations, no idea why

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, freeze, task-parallel-library

I'm running a Parallel.For loop on a little over 7500 objects. Inside that for loop, I'm doing a number of things to each of those objects, specifically calling two web services and two internal methods. The web services simply inspect the object, process and return a string that i then set as a property on the object. Same goes for the two internal methods.

I'm not writing anything out to disk or reading from disk.

I also update the UI in a winforms app with a label and progress bar to let the user know where it's at. Here's the code:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  Parallel.For(0, upperLimit, (i, loopState) =>
  {
     if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        loopState.Stop();
     lblProgressBar.Invoke(
       (Action)
       (() => lblProgressBar.Text = string.Format("Processing record {0} of {1}.", (progressCounter++), upperLimit)));
     progByStep.Invoke(
       (Action)
       (() => progByStep.Value = (progressCounter - 1)));

      CallSvc1(entity[i]);
      Conversion1(entity[i]);
      CallSvc2(entity[i]);
      Conversion2(entity[i]);
  });
}, cancellationToken);
```

This is taking place on a Win7 32bit machine.

Any ideas as to why this suddenly freezes when the incrementer is around 1370 or so (It's been 1361, 1365 and 1371)?

Any ideas as to how I can debug this and see what's locking if anything?

**EDIT:**
Some answers to the comments below:
@BrokenGlass - No, no interop. I'll try the x86 compilation and let you know.

@chibacity - Because it's on a background task, it's not freezing the UI. Up until the time it freezes, the progress bar and label tick along at about 2 every second. When it freezes, it just stops moving. I can verify that the number that it stops at has been processed, but no more. CPU usage on a dual core 2.2GHz is minimal during the operation at 3-4% each and 1-2% once it freezes.

@Henk Holterman - It takes around 10-12 minutes to get to 1360 and yes, I can verify that all of those records have been processed but not the remaining records.

@CodeInChaos - Thanks, I'll try that! The code does work if I take out the parallel, it just takes forever and a day. I haven't tried restricting the number of threads, but will.

**EDIT 2:**
Some details as to what's going on with the webservices

Basically what's going on with the web services is that they pass in some data and receive data (an XmlNode). That node is then used in the Conversion1 process which in turn sets another property on the entity which is sent to the CallSvc2 method and so on. It looks like this:

```
private void CallSvc1(Entity entity)
{
    var svc = new MyWebService();
    var node = svc.CallMethod(entity.SomeProperty);
    entity.FieldToUpdate1.LoadXml(node.InnerXml);
}
private void Conversion1(Entity entity)
{
    // Do some xml inspection/conversion stuff
    if (entity.FieldToUpdate1.SelectSingleNode("SomeNode") == "something") {
        entity.FieldToUpdate2 = SomethingThatWasConverted;
    }
    else {
        // Do some more logic
    }
}
private void CallSvc2(Entity entity)
{
    var svc = new SomeOtherWebService();
    var xmlNode = svc.MethodToCall(entity.FieldToUpdate2.InnerXml);
    entity.AnotherXmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlNode.InnerXml);
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty straightforward stuff. There's a lot going on in some of the conversion methods, but none of it should be blocking. And as noted below, there are 1024 threads in "waiting" status that are all sitting on the webservice calls. I read here http://www.albahari.com/threading/ that the MaxThreads is defaulted to 1023 for .Net 4 on 32 bit machine.

How can I release those waiting threads given what I have here?

Comment: I had a similar problem before - I would try building the project in x86 mode to see if that changes anything. You wouldn't happen to do any InterOp in your tasks?

Comment: Is it freezing or just going very slowly. How is CPU usage?

Comment: Haven't worked with TPL yet, but can't you just break in the debugger and check in which method-call the functions stopped? And does the code work if you replace it with a normal for loop? And what happens if you use `Parallel.For` but restrict it to one or two threads?

Comment: You should make your web service calls async.  BeginGetResponse instead of GetResponse.  This will release the thread back to the pool.

Comment: Given what you've said, I think we need to know about the guts of the CallSvc methods. Any chance you can share a sample of how you're calling the services? Is it WCF, WebClient, HttpRequest...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible explanation: you've got the process into a state where it can't create any more threads, which is preventing work from making  progress, which is why everything's grinding to a halt.

Frankly, whether or not that hypothesis turns out to be correct, you need to take a completely different approach to this. `Parallel.For` is the wrong way to solve this. (`Parallel` is best suited to CPU-bound work. What you have here is IO-bound work.) If you truly need to have thousands of web service requests in progress, you need to move over to using asynchronous code, instead of multithreaded code. If you use async APIs, you'll be able to start thousands of requests simultaneously while using only a handful of threads.

Whether those requests will actually be able to execute simultaneously is another matter - whether you use your current "thread apocalypse" implementation or a more efficient async implementation, you may well be running into throttling. (.NET can sometimes limit the number of requests it'll actually make.) So you can ask to make as many requests as you like, but you might find that almost all of your requests are sat waiting for earlier ones to complete. E.g. I think `WebRequest` limits concurrent connections to any single domain to just 2... Firing up 1000+ threads (or 1000+ async requests) is just going to result in loads more requests sitting waiting to be one of the 2 current requests!

You should do your own throttling. You need to decide how many outstanding requests to have simultaneously, and make sure you only start that many requests at once. Just asking `Parallel` to launch as many as it can as quickly as it can will bog everything down.

**Updated to add:**

A quick fix might be to use the overload of `Parallel.For` that accepts a `ParallelOptions` object - you can set its `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property to limit the number of concurrent requests. That would stop this thread-heavy implementation from actually running out of threads. But it remains an inefficient solution to the problem. (And for all I know, you do actually need to make thousands of concurrent requests. If you're writing a web crawler, for example, that's actually a reasonable thing to want to do. `Parallel` is not the right class for that job though. Use async operations. If the web service proxies you're using support the APM (BeginXxx, EndXxx), you can wrap that up in `Task` objects - `Task.TaskFactory` offers a `FromAsync` that'll provide a task representing an async operation in progress.

But if you are going to try to have thousands of requests in flight at once, you do need to think carefully about your throttling strategy. Just throwing requests out there as fast as possible is unlikely to be the optimal strategy.

Comment: If the webservices I'm trying to consume don't support APM (BeginXXX and EndXXX) but have SvcNameCompleted event handler and SvcNameAsync, can I still use TaskFactory FromAsync?

Comment: No, TaskFactory.FromAsync is designed specifically for the APM. However, if you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd997423 the "Exposing Complex EAP Operations As Tasks" section does show how you can deal with the XxxAsync/XxxCompleted pattern. (The EAP, as that pattern's known.)

Comment: I agree mostly with the update part, the # of threads should be limited. To a low number, N <= 10 or so. And that makes the whole async pattern less important. While Ian is absolutely right about APM being more efficient, using a handful of threads for this (big) task isn't so bad.

Comment: A handful of threads would indeed be fine, but only if that actually works for the problem at hand. That rather depends on what the application really needs do to. There are some tasks (e.g. web crawling) for which it's perfectly reasonable to have thousands of requests active at once (even if there are only 2 or 3 to any single website at a time). So we'd really need to know: what is Chris Conway trying to do? Why does he have thousands of calls to make? (From the code, I rather suspect that the ultimate answer will be a fundamental restructuring of the web service he's using... Batches FTW!)

Answer (score 5):

Run the app in the VS debugger.  When it seems to lock up, tell VS to Debug: Break All.  Then go to Debug: Windows: Threads and look at the threads in your process. Some of them should be showing stack traces that are in your parallel for loop, and that will tell you what they were doing when the process was stopped by the debugger.

Comment: There's well over 1000 threads in the debug thread window and they all say the location of the thread is on one of the two web service calls. They all show yellow and WorkerThread in the category column and say "In a sleep, wait, or join". Could this be the problem, the sheer volume of waiting threads? If so, what can I do about it? I don't see anything crashing or throwing exceptions.

Comment: That sounds pretty serious.  Try dialing back a bit from the parallel loop.  Make sure it works as a straight-up sequential loop, then try limiting the number of threads in the parallel loop.

Comment: Looking at the Parallel Tasks window shows that it's exactly 1024 waiting threads, all just sitting on the web service calls. Not sure why it can't release those threads back to the pool. The non web service call threads are returned to the pool. Hmmmmmmm

Comment: @Chris: 1000 Threads or 1000 Tasks? Makes a whole lot of difference.

Comment: The TPL Tasks window says the Category is Worker Thread and there 1023 of those. 1 Main thread is there too and that is the program.main.